# How to get file ID from box.com by passing the file name in python

Tags: python-3.x, django, box

How to obtain file_id from "file name" in Box.com API

Not sure which call will I make from this https://developer.box.com/reference/#searching-for-content.

I want to pass filename and get file id of that filename.

I am using python SDK

Answer (score -1):

The method to retrieve file information is found in the [documentation here](https://developer.box.com/reference/get-files-id/)

So if you are using python, it should look something like this according to the API documentation:

```
file_id = '11111'
file_info = client.file(file_id).get()
print('File name: "{0}" '.format(file_info.name))
```

Comment: I am ok with that but I want to get that file id using file name. I can get the id from front end by travelling to that file but i want to get that id in python by passing the file name

Comment: Maybe try the [file metadata](https://developer.box.com/reference/resources/file--full/#param-metadata-%253Ckey%253E) after retrieving it using the [file name](https://developer.box.com/reference/resources/file--full/#param-name) query.